# How to implement a change listener

Tags: android, listener

If I have a variable, String X; how do I implement a changelistener for it?  I want to have the variable in another Activity and monitor for any change to the variable's value in a Service. Probably by sending a broadcast intent if there has been a change.

It is the change in value that I am looking for.  If the string is the same string or if the String has been replaced with a different one.  and be able to express this in a boolean way.  True for the same value unchanged and false for value changed.

Comment: are you taking input from user in String X?

Comment: string x will be the path name of the file, for example: /mnt/sdcard/music/testSong.mp3  so i am not taking input from the user.  the input will be getting that string from the content provider database