# Alternative to change listener for detecting change in a variable's value

Tags: java, android, variables, listener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924909/how-to-implement-a-change-listener)

I know that some will use a change listener or some custom made listener to detect a change in the value of a variable.

Is there a way to code this without using a listener.  A simple java way to do this?  Any ideas?

I am looking for alternative ways to do this. Is there a better way or is using a listener the best way?   This is a subject that can be called "best practices"

Any time the value of a variable changes in an Activity it will be reported to a Service by way of broadcast intent to a broadcast receiver that is nested inside of the Service.

Comment: did you double post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924909/how-to-implement-a-change-listener

Comment: no double post, to opposite questions.   this question covers a simple java way to detect change. and the other post is how to implement a change listener.   after looking at the two ways of solving the problem, the best way will be used.  More ways means more possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hide the variable behind a Setter Function. Then every time the setter is called, the variable is modified.

Comment: +1 The only logical way to do it